# Why did the Cardassians refine uridium ore on Terok Nor in space instead of on Bajor?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Hauling unprocessed ore into orbit to be refined seems extremely inefficient. The Cardassians occupied Bajor for 50 years, so they had plenty of time to build refineries on the surface.

Comment: Opinion here, we have seen orbital mining facilities before (like the one where Data discovers sentience in the worker bots), I imagine it's easier to move an orbital facility over deposits, rather than dismantling are rebuilding to follow the ore. It also allows some security, harder to bomb by rebels.

Comment: Can they not just transport ore too? Straight into the holding bays?

Comment: Excellent question! Even security reasons don't make up for the effort to haul unrefined ore up into space against the gravity well of a planet. Imho it just shows the deep lack of understanding for the energy needed to do so on the writers side. After all the original function of Terok Nor could have been designed to be something else.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith, that question has actually been covered: [Why do cultures with transport technology use conventional mining methods?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68906/why-do-cultures-with-transport-technology-use-conventional-mining-methods/92168#92168)

Comment: @T.J.L. Yeah my point is you have the slave labour pulling the ore out of the mine and then that is transported.

Comment: Presumably the refinement process requires microgravity.  (Or has to be in space for some other reason, e.g., the surrounding area has to be mostly vacuum.)

Comment: The station can move - was it always in orbit of Bajor? Might it have been used elsewhere first?

Comment: @ThruGog The station was built by Bajoran laborers, so to build it somewhere other than the Bajoran system and later move it there would be odd.

Comment: D'oh! You got me there.

Comment: Doing so would be inefficient for us, but I've always thought the Star Trek universe had little trouble leaving a gravity well.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that the Bajoran Uridium ore didn't have to come from the planet Bajor.  Maybe it came from another astronomical body in the Bajoran system, a body with a small escape body so that the total escape energy and interplanetary transport energy would have been smaller than the energy to lift the ore up from Bajor.

Possibly the Cardassians only abandoned the Bajoran system after they had mined and exhausted all the valuable Uridium and other ores in the various bodies of the Bajoran System.

There is no canonical proof of this theory.

Evidence in favor of it is:

1. That it takes much less energy to mine an small astronomical body and move the ore to a station in orbit around a planet than it takes to mine the ores on the planet and move them up to an orbiting space station.
2. In "[The Nagus](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/411.htm)" Jake is teaching Nog to read and Nog says:

> The lar, largest planet is Bajor. It has three moons?

3. in "[Progress](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/415.htm)" there is the following log:

> Station log. Stardate 46844.3. With the help of the Federation, Bajor is about to commence its first large-scale energy transfer, the tapping of the molten core of its fifth moon, Jeraddo.

So Bajor's moons have numbers up to five (or higher) and yet a probably nearly contemporary source says that Bajor has three moons.

Thus it seems that the number of Bajor's moons changes.  If Bajor had at least two small asteroid sized moons full of Uridium ore the Cardassians may have totally demolished them to get the ores, leaving Bajor with just three remaining moons.

Comment: I had never noticed the discrepancy in the number of moons before.

Comment: Other uses for the station would include ship repair, a haven for visiting officials so they wouldn't need to actually go to Bajor, a trade station, guard "tower" to watch over the Bajoran prisoners/slaves, etc. And in one of the "mirror" episodes we see that the Terrans have even attached a dry dock to the docking ring, allowing for local starship construction.

Comment: I just substituted the fictional substance Uridium for the real element Iridium in my answer.  I just can't get used to the creators using a fictional substance Uridium which sounds so much like the real element Iridium.

Comment: I recall references to "strip mining my planet" and widespread ecological devastation on Bajor. That would suggest that there was at least some mining on the planet.

Comment: @Xantec Nog **was** just learning to read, he may've got it wrong.

Comment: The bridgekeeper will ask us about the five moons.  Three moons sire.

Comment: Has anything relevant come to light since this was answered ~6 years ago?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Well, I'm pretty sure this answer is wrong but I'm blowed if I can remember why I think that.

Comment: @Xantec "That's no *moon!*",  "*This* is Bajor Luna 5!", etc.

Comment: @Valorum would a bounty help jog your memory?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - It's in one of the factbooks but not the Technical Manual.

Comment: @Valorum: I am rather tempted to write an answer of the form "They were mining ore from all over the place, some of it on-planet and some of it off-planet, and processing it all in orbit is cheaper than building multiple facilities. Besides, it all had to go into space eventually so they could ship it off to the rest of the Cardassian empire." But that would run into the same logical-but-not-authoritative problem that this answer has.

Comment: @Kevin the bounty is almost up, so if you wanted to.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: My comment was somewhat flippant. I don't think I can write such an answer and have it be of adequate quality.

Answer (score 4):

The show's [bible](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/3_Deep_Space_Nine/Star_Trek_-_Deep_Space_Nine_Bible.pdf) (a document created in advance of filming to give writers and producers an idea of the main themes that will be explored) gives us a couple of pieces of information that aren't made explicit in the show, both of which give us some insight into the Cardassian's thinking behind placing Terok Nor into orbit, as opposed to having it on the ground.

---

Firstly, the station is processing uridium ore from mines **on Bajor itself** as well as 'monitoring' mining operations on the ground, with a literal overview. Since we can assume that there were mines at various locations on the planet, the proximity of the station to the ground means that transporters (or impulse transports) can be used to easily move the ore from the surface to the station, to be processed for onward transit to Cardassia Prime.

Since the ore will need to be taken from the mine to a processing centre *and then taken from the processing centre into orbit*, you might just as well skip the middle step and have the processing happen in orbit to begin with, saving a journey.

> The station designated DS9 by Starfleet was assembled haphazardly over
> several years by Cardassian and Bajoran work teams and anybody else
> who happened to offer services at a premium. **It was used by the
> Cardassians primarily to monitor mining operations on Bajor and to
> service incoming and outgoing crews.** About two hundred people, mostly
> Bajorans, still live there. By episode three, there will be about
> fifty Starfleet officers and crewmen stationed there.

Secondly, the surface is simply not a safe place to put a facility like this. The Bajora are a wily bunch who positively revel in blowing up Cardassian-operated complexes. Having the station in orbit gives the Cardassians the ability to prevent infiltration and keep a much closer eye on the Bajorans on the station to make sure they're not up to no good.

> Due to the turmoil on the planet, **it is deemed unsafe to create a
> Federation base on the surface so, at the request of the provisional
> government, Starfleet takes command of a recently abandoned Cardassian
> space station in orbit of Bajor.**

Comment: Regarding "you might just as well skip the middle step", it takes a _lot_ more energy to move mass into a planet's orbit than along its surface, so it needs a big future-tech hand-wave for that to be reasonable. I guess if the valuable materials account for the majority of the ore's mass, it might make sense, but we're back to speculation: your quote doesn't actually mention them *refining* ore there *at all*.

Comment: @IMSoP What in the setting gives you any reason to suspect anyone seriously cares about energy efficiency outside of emergency situations?  The Federation and all the other major civilizations are basically in a post-scarcity economy, all the way down to energy production. Not to mention that things like warp technology means they can completely defy everything we know about energy consumption and limits right out of the gates.

Comment: @IMSoP - Shuttles the size of small cars are capable of flight from a planet's surface, into orbit and then to other planets in other solar systems. That's a pretty big hand-wave.

Answer (score 1):

The season 3 episode "Civil Defence" showed raw uridium explodes when electrically charged when Commander Sisko, O'brien and Jake improvise an explosive capable of breaching a hatch in the ore processing facility with just a pile of ore and some wire stripped out of a light fitting.

Considering the resistance movement on Bajor itself the Cardassians wouldn't want such a potent and easy to weaponise material to be accessible so they instead had it transported into orbit to be processed under the intense security protocols seen in "Civil Defence".

Comment: Surely the opposite is true. If you have a powerful explosive, the last place you'd want it is on a space station...

Comment: @Valorum Given how ships and everything else in space explode in fantastic and asymmetric ways, I think we can safely conclude that everyone in the galaxy ultimately had to accept that high explosives were just a necessary evil for high tech (post-warp) space operations.